# Lo que agrego en el input se me borra cuando quito el foco del input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Cuando quiero agregar un fabricante, este mismo se borra ,al hacer click en el select o en cualquier lado.

Código de la ventana cuando abro agregar fabricantes

```html
</div> <!-- /form-group-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="brandStatus" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Estado: </label>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id="brandStatus" name="brandStatus">
            <option value="">-- Seleciona--</option>
            <option value="1">Disponible</option>
            <option value="2">No disponible</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /form-group-->
```

---

Puede ser que el error venga de alguna librería de js? O en el orden que tengo los link y script en el head

Comment: hice una prueba y tu código funciona correctamente. en que navegador lo estas usando?

Comment: Yo también probé tu código y está bien. Funciona tanto en Chrome, como en Firefox y en Internet Explore Edge.